# Create a dictionary of generic variables in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics

I'm looking for a way to store a generics subclass in a dictionary but I'm having problems.

In the following example I'm trying to create a dictionary of objects that I know will subclass `Entity<T>`. I'm successfully storing single instances of my sub classes `FloatEntity` and `StringEntity` in an `Entity` type var but when I try to store the same in a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, Entity>` I get an error.

```swift
class Entity<T> {
    var _value: T
    var value: T { get { return _value } set {_value = newValue}}

    init (defaultValue: T) {
        _value = defaultValue
    }
}

class FloatEntity: Entity<Float> {
}

class StringEntity: Entity<String> {
}

func run () {
    let variable1: Entity = FloatEntity (defaultValue: 1)
    let variable2: Entity = StringEntity (defaultValue: "")
    var dictionary: Dictionary<String, Entity> = [
        "One": FloatEntity (defaultValue: 1),
        "Two": StringEntity (defaultValue: ""),
    ]
    print (variable1)
    print (variable2)
    print (dictionary)
}
```

The error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'FloatEntitiy' to expected dictionary value 
>   type 'Entity'

Can anyone advise on how I might go about using a dictionary to store generics like this?

Comment: 1. Is this your real `Entity` class? As simple as it is at the moment, there's no need for it. It's basically just `Any`. 2. At a minimum, there's no need for the `_value` variable. Just do `var value: T`. No need for the `set` and `get`.

Comment: 3. Is there more to these "subclasses"? Why not just do `typealias FloatEntity = Entity<Float>` ?

Comment: "objects that I know will subclass Entity<T>" I don't think you do know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`variable1` and `variable2` are not of type `Entity` but are in fact `Entity<Float>` and `Entity<String>` which are two unrelated types.  Use a `protocol` to unite them:

```
protocol EntityProtocol { }

class Entity<T> : EntityProtocol {
    var _value: T
    var value: T { get { return _value } set {_value = newValue}}

    init (defaultValue: T) {
        _value = defaultValue
    }
}

class FloatEntity: Entity<Float> {
}

class StringEntity: Entity<String> {
}

func run () {
    let variable1: Entity = FloatEntity (defaultValue: 1)
    let variable2: Entity = StringEntity (defaultValue: "")
    var dictionary: Dictionary<String, EntityProtocol> = [
        "One": FloatEntity (defaultValue: 1),
        "Two": StringEntity (defaultValue: ""),
    ]
    print (variable1)
    print (variable2)
    print (dictionary)
}
```

Comment: Having taken some advice from the other answers I think my use case is flawed. That said I Think this answers my question most directly is I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what you've provided so far, this is not looking like a good use of a generic. If the idea is to store values in a dictionary where each value might be a string or might be a float, that sounds like more like an enum with associated values (this is playground code):

```
enum StringOrFloat {
    case string(String)
    case float(Float)
}
let v1 = StringOrFloat.string("meaning of life")
let v2 = StringOrFloat.float(42)
var d = Dictionary<String,StringOrFloat>()
d["hey"] = v1
d["ho"] = v2
```

And here's a way of extracting a value:

```
if let val = d["hey"] {
    switch val {
    case .string(let s):
        print("it is a string, namely", s)
    case .float(let f):
        print("it is a float, namely", f)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift generics are invariant, thus `Entity<B>` is not a subclass of `Entity<A>`, even if B would be a subclass of A. So you cannot store the same types using the superclass of `Entity` in a dictionary.

You could achieve what you want by using `AnyObject` as your dictionary value, e.g. with this code:-

```
var dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
  "One": FloatEntity (defaultValue: 1),
  "Two": FloatEntity (defaultValue: 2),
]
```

I don't think you can extract a type-erased `Entity` from that though (happy to be corrected). But you could do something like this:-

```
let v = dictionary["One"]
if let v1 = v as? FloatEntity
{
  ...
}
```